# How to pass image references?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Context:**
I am developing a custom Wordpress theme.

**Objective:**
On the home page, when you click, "stamps" are dotted about the window. I have the js functioning. Here's an example in which you can see exactly what I'm trying to do: https://omg-draft.superhi.com/

**Problem:**
I need a way to access the veggies in my main.js. I'm having trouble passing them from my functions.php to main.js. I have enqueued the js file and passed in the image files. In the console, I get back 'veggies is not defined'.

Here's the code from functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'omedte_get_scripts' );

function omedte_get_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('main.js', get_template_directory_uri() . "/main.js", array(), null, true);

    $veggies = array(
        "beetroot" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/beetroot.svg'),
        "broccoli" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/broccoli.svg'),
        "capsicum" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/capsicum.svg'),
        "carrot" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/carrot.svg'),
        "corn" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/corn.svg'),
        "gourd" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/gourd.svg'),
        "kale" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/kale.svg'),
        "pumpkin" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/pumpkin.svg'),
        "spinach" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/spinach.svg')
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'omedte_javascript_file', 'veggies', $veggies );
}
```

and here's my main.js:

```
let carrot = veggies.carrot;
let broccoli = veggies.broccoli;
let capsicum = veggies.capsicum;

let stamps = [
  carrot,
  broccoli,
  capsicum
]
```

Comment: Hmm I couldn't find it to be applicable for what I'm trying to do, but thank you!

Comment: Would I put that in functions.php or main.js? main.js won't accept php, and I'm not sure how to access the variables in main.js if json_econde happens in functions.php.

Comment: Ahh that did the trick, we're getting there! The images are registering in main.js, and the 'click, stamp' function is working on the homepage except that the veggie images aren't showing up, the broken image link (?) icon is instead. I'm thinking that may have something to do with the image array in functions which looks like this:

wp_localize_script('main.js', 'php_data', 
  $veggies = array(
   "beetroot" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/broccoli.svg'),
   "broccoli" => get_theme_file_uri('/assets/broccoli.svg')
));

Comment: Then please update the question with your new attempts and what is wrong

Answer (score -1):

Might not be the only issue, but your handles don't match in your enqueue and localise statements.

Refer [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)